# Android - Preventing code 304 on HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, http, http-headers, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I wish to perform an HTTP request, WITHOUT any form of caching.
I use HttpUrlConnection, and setting every possible parameter for disabling caching, yet I keep getting code 304 after the 2nd request, every run.

I use the following headers:

```
"Cache-Control: no-cache"
"Cache-Control: no-store"
"Pragma: no-cache"
```

And also setting `httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false)`

If I kill the app (recents list), it performs the 1st request again normally, then back to 304.

How to force a full request and get 200 every time?

Code that initializes HttpUrlConnection

```
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpUrlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
httpUrlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpUrlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-store");
httpUrlConnection.addRequestProperty("pragma", "no-cache");
httpUrlConnection.setIfModifiedSince(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` should work as per the documentation at [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html),

but,you can also verify the cached response through

`connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");`

Comment: try with `If-Modified-Since`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: try setting this to `false`
`httpUrlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169342/discussion-between-kashyap-jimuliya-and-sirknigget).

Comment: I need redirects. There is no reason to change that.